# String.split() JavaScript method is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, string, firefox, split

I am trying to split a string in javascript . it works fine in chrome, but it is not working in firefox

code

```
var a="1#abc";
var b=a.split('#');
```

The error on cole is `TypeError: response.split is not a function`

The response in firefox is not in string. It is as `[Object XMLDocument]` It is not being converted by `toString()` method. HowI can convert it in to string

Comment: [It should work fine in any browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: but it is not working in Firefox :(

Comment: `var a="1#abc"; var b=a.split('#'); console.log(b);` -> `["1", "abc"]`. Seems to work for me

Comment: The only way this can happen is if a) `a` isn't *actually* a string (and the example you posted is a simplified version of the problem you're experiencing), or b) *some* other code (your responsibility to find it in your application) is **overriding** `String.prototype.split` to something non-`function`.

Comment: Try to write your test code in Firefox and it'll run. The problem isn't in split() but somewhere in (your) code around it.

Comment: It sounds like your "string" came from XMLHttpRequest, and you used `.responseXML` or `.response` when you meant `.responseText`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't know what exaclty is happening but you can try to convert your variable into a string before splitting:

```
var a = '1#abc';
var b = a.toString().split('#');
```

Comment: Lost an hour before finding this. Why String.split() should stop QtQuick 1.0 javascript execution on a perfect valid string? Simply, because it's not a string.

Comment: "Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined" getting this error in my case

Comment: Then your object is undefined and not a proper String object

Comment: @Avio, Why it isn't a string, please?

Comment: @shireefkhatab: Appearently, it is now considered as a string, tested in Chtome. Firefox and IE. typeof a gives "string" in all browsers.